# Docker (Ubuntu)+SQL Server 2022+FTS?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, full-text-search

I am running Docker (Ubuntu)+SQL Server 2022 using docker-compose file

```
-----
version: "3.4"
services:
    sql-server-db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
        ports:
          - "52477:1433"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "dobedo#123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
-----
```

It works fine, but

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
---
0
```

How to run Docker with SQLServer2022 + FTS ?

I have created 2 files docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.new (as it was described below). After run the >docker-compose up -d I have recived

```
PS D:\_Docker\SQLServer> docker-compose up -d
Building 1.1s (6/7)
[sql-server-db internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.new                                             0.0s
 transferring dockerfile: 736B                                                                               0.0s
  [sql-server-db internal] load .dockerignore                                                                    0.0s
  transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
  [sql-server-db internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest                          0.0s
 [sql-server-db 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest                                            0.0s
 CACHED [sql-server-db 2/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq curl apt-transport-https                  0.0s
 ERROR [sql-server-db 3/4] RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts                                              1.1s
------
 > [sql-server-db 3/4] RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts:
#0 0.278 Reading package lists...
#0 0.927 Building dependency tree...
#0 1.073 Reading state information...
**#0 1.090 E: Unable to locate package mssql-server-fts**
```

My Dockerfile.new:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq curl apt-transport-https 
#RUN add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022.list)"
RUN apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq curl apt-transport-https && \
    # Get official Microsoft repository configuration
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

You should add the package `apt install -y mssql-server-fts`.

So, in your case, create a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
USER root
RUN apt update && apt install -y mssql-server-fts
```

and modify the docker-compose file accordingly:

```
services:
  sql-server-db:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ...
```

Comment: #0 3.470 E: Unable to locate package mssql-server-fts